# How to avoid Await.result?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I have my `Play` app, and I want to implement kind of uniqueness validation by myself, I use `Slick`, so it's natural that I do a simple `sum(1) where` call and if that `count` is more than zero I set the error to my `case class object`. So I can't imagine the workaround to avoid `Await.result` on my DB query, because I need to set the error right in the current time.

But I now that `Await.result` is really bad practice, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use map on the future:

```
db.run(query.result) map { response =>
  //do whatever you want with the response
}
```

In this case you get the response but it is not blocking as `Await.result` is.

Edit: so for the code you showed in your comment, it would look like:

```
def exists(tableName: String, column: String, value: Any): Future[Boolean] = {
  val query = dbConfig.db.run(sql"SELECT COUNT(1) from #$tableName WHERE #$column = ${value.toString};".as[Int])

  query.map(_.sum > 0)
}
```

Then where you need to call `exists` you will do

```
exists(...) map  { result => 
if (result == true) 
  //doSomething
}
```

Comment: yes, sure, but let's say I need to perform validation, like:

presence validation + presence validation + uniqueness validation + uniqueness validation

So I can't see the way to make this `Future` stuff chainable here

First two will be `Boolean` type, and if I use map, this one will be `Future[Boolean]`, I can't come up with the solution for this

Comment: Inside the map the response is not of type Future[Boolean] but Boolean. So you can make whatever checks you need and after it will return a Future[Boolean]. Post your code if you want me to explain you on a real situation.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ASssHyvN

this is minimal code which should show the problem, as you can see current implementation uses `Await.result`

Comment: Yes, for the this step I can do it, I don't know what to do in `CountryValidator`

Comment: and even this doesn't work as well

http://pastebin.com/Kx9xMt06

And this: http://pastebin.com/jr3zmgj1

Comment: Anywy I've fixed it up, ty :)